# How to constraint scoped routes with dynamic parameters to only have a specific combination of parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a Rails app for a forum and have this:

routes.rb

```
@@category_filters=/general|off-topic|ruby-on-rails/
@@subcategory_filters = /announcements|news|member-introductions|suggestions|
                     developers|tutorials|jobs-and-projects|miscellaneous|
                     funny-stuff/

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|de/ do
    ...
    scope '/:category/:subcategory', category: @@category_filters,
                                     subcategory: @@subcategory_filters do
      resources :posts
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Here I want my routes for `posts` to have 2 parameters in the URL called `category` and `subcategory`

There is this structure in my app(it's a forum)

- general

  - announcements
  - suggestions
  - member-introductions
- ruby-on-rails

  - news
  - developers
  - tutorials
- off-topic

  - miscellaneous
  - jobs-and-projects
  - funny-stuff

now this works ok as of now with the `routes.rb` that I presented you above but I want to further constraint the routing to be so that posts only have a specific combination of parameters in the url

For example this should be ok:

```
.../general/announcements/posts/...
```

But not this:

```
.../general/tutorials/posts...
```

Because according to my site design `tutorials` is not a subcategory of `general` but of `ruby-on-rails`

Has anyone an idea how to change the `routes.rb` file so that it works like I want it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regular expressions here you should just use a [custom route constraint](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints):

```
class Category
  OPTIONS = {
    "general" => [
      "announcements",
      "suggestions",
      "member-introductions",
    ],
    "ruby-on-rails" => [
      "news",
      "developers",
      "tutorials",
    ],
    "off-topic" => [
      "miscellaneous",
      "jobs-and-projects",
      "funny-stuff",
    ]
  }
end

class CategoryConstraint 
  def matches?(request)
    options = Category::OPTIONS
    category = request.params[:category]
    subcategory = request.params[:subcategory]

    options[category] && options[category].include?(subcategory)  
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts, constraints: CategoryConstraint.new
end
```

You can simplify this into a DSL using [only](https://github.com/coreyward/only).

Comment: I have just copied it into my routes.rb and now no routes work like this one: `http://localhost:3000/de/general/announcements/posts/new`

Answer (score -1):

I did it like this with a wild card:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  @category_filters    = /(?x)general\/suggestions|
                              general\/member-introduction|
                              general\/announcements|
                              off-topic\/jobs-and-projects|
                              off-topic\/miscellaneous|
                              off-topic\/funny-stuff|
                              ruby-on-rails\/news|
                              ruby-on-rails\/developers|
                              ruby-on-rails\/tutorials/
  scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|de/ do
   ...
    scope '*category', category: @category_filters do
      resources :posts, only: %i[new edit index show]
    end
    ...
end
```